# vertical-align isn't bringing my fields to the top of the DIV

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I’m trying to align search fields.  All my elements are within a parent container, which has the style

```
#statSearchFields {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

The elements themselves have look like

```
<div class="searchField">
Start Date<br>
<input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="06/28/2014" placeholder="Start Date" class="datepicker hasDatepicker">
</div>
```

but when I put them in my container, they appear off-center.  Here is the example fiddle — https://jsfiddle.net/n73ao02h/1/ .  How do I bring everything into alignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `vertical-align: top;` to the `.searchField` selector.

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n73ao02h/2/

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align: top` isn't being inherited from your ID.  Add the following to your CSS and you will have the results you would expect.

```
.searchField {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Note: You should remove the `vertical-align` property from your `#statSearchFields` ID.